# When I disable and enable my window, borders disappear

Tags: c, winapi

When I disable and re-enable the windows in `AddControl`, the `WS_BORDER` style in the window disappears. Why? link that contains the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41IQ4.png) of the program toggling off the border in "nuova prenotazione"

The case in window procedure:

```c
case CERCA_UT_RI:
                {
                    MessageBeep(MB_RIGHT);
                    //mostra varie message box in base all output, se ritorna 1 vuol dire che ha trovato l'utente ricercato
                    if(Cerca_utM(HricercaMain)==1){
                        //mettiamo la ricerca nella variabile globale così da passarla alle altre funzioni
                        GetWindowText(HricercaMain, ricerca, 20);
                        //Riattiva tutte le finestre
                        EnableAllWindow(hWnd);      
                    }
                } 
                break;
```

Controls of the window procedure:

```c
void AddControls(HWND hWnd)//dichiariamo la nostra addcontrol e processeremo ovviamente wm_create ove si crea la finestra
{
    //-------------------------------------UTENTE----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    HWinRicerca = CreateWindowW(L"static",L"Ricerca Utente",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER|WS_THICKFRAME,350,40,250,135,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"static",L"Nome :",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER,30,35,50,20,HWinRicerca,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    HricercaMain = CreateWindowW(L"edit", NULL,  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,80,35,130,20,HWinRicerca,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"Conferma",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,435,115,70,40,hWnd,(HMENU)CERCA_UT_RI,NULL,NULL);
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //--------------------------------Prenotazione--------------------------------------------------
    hPreMain = CreateWindowW(L"static",L"Nuova Prenotazione",WS_DISABLED |WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER|WS_THICKFRAME,100,225,280,220,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    hTBid = CreateWindowW(L"static",L"id Rist :",WS_VISIBLE |WS_DISABLED | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER|ES_NUMBER,160,260,60,20,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    HPreid = CreateWindowW(L"edit", NULL, WS_DISABLED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_NUMBER,220,260,60,20,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    hTBpre = CreateWindowW(L"static",L"Data Prenotazione :",WS_DISABLED |WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD |ES_NUMBER,160,300,130,20,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    HPreGio = CreateWindowW(L"edit", L"g",WS_DISABLED |WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_NUMBER| WS_BORDER,160,330,30,20,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    HPreMese = CreateWindowW(L"edit", L"m",WS_DISABLED | WS_BORDER |WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD  | ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_NUMBER,205,330,30,20,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    HPreAnno = CreateWindowW(L"edit", L"y",WS_DISABLED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD  | ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_NUMBER| WS_BORDER,250,330,40,20,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    hbutton = CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"Conferma",WS_DISABLED |WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,190,380,70,40,hWnd,(HMENU)PRE_NUOVO,NULL,NULL);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //limitiamo il massimo degli input inseribili nelle edit box di giorno/mese
    const int maximum_length = 2;
    SendMessage(HPreGio, EM_SETLIMITTEXT, maximum_length, 0);
    SendMessage(HPreMese, EM_SETLIMITTEXT, maximum_length, 0);
}
```

and the enable all window procedure:

```
void EnableAllWindow(HWND hWnd)
{
    EnableWindow(hPreMain, true);
    EnableWindow(hbutton, true);
    EnableWindow(HPreGio, true);
    EnableWindow(HPreMese, true);
    EnableWindow(HPreAnno, true);
    EnableWindow(HPreid, true);
    EnableWindow(hTBid, true);
    EnableWindow(hTBpre, true);
}
```

Comment: There is no function `EnableAllWindow` so that must be custom code.  Perhaps you should show that.

Comment: Your variables are a mix of the (original?) Italian and English. For example, I guess `HricercaMain` is the same as `HresearchMain`. Without a proper, minimal example, we cannot know what your issue is.

Comment: And why don't you use `WS_DISABLED` if you want them to start disabled?

Comment: Are you using "Visual Styles"?  That will intentionally remove border and make controls look "flat".

Comment: sorry i was trying to translate all of them in english

Comment: if i do with ws_disable will it fix

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67908861/edit) you question to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With such example, we will be able to reproduce your problem, understand it and try to solve it.

Comment: i changed the question and leave the original code without translating it, is it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the code and was able to reproduce the problem, but I think it was caused by the redrawing of the static control.

You can try not to enable the `hPreMain` window, it will work fine:

[image]

You can also try to modify the coordinates of the window to determine if it is causing the problem:

[image]

And when you enable the window, it redraws on the main window and it covers the border. I think your `hPreMain` window should not use the `static` control but a custom window, which will work normally:

[image]